# Issue with bash one liner

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a bash one liner to get the latest logfile to cat and/or tail:

```
for i in /mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_*.log; do ls -t $i | head -n1 ; done
```

But get all of the matching files:

```
/mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_2020-06-03-09:00:01:345123169.log
/mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_2020-06-04-09:00:01:370667894.log
/mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_2020-06-04-19:15:27:274135912.log
/mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_2020-06-05-09:00:02:020131150.log
/mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_2020-06-06-09:00:02:238963148.log
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also, if I wanted to tail (or cat) that, would I have to declare another variable and tail -f that $variable ?

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to do a bash one liner to get the latest logfile

You could use

```
latestfile=$(/bin/ls -t /mnt/usbdrive/backup/filelog_*.log | /bin/tail -1)
```

assuming you don't have spaces (or semicolons, etc...) in your file names

See [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [tail(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) and carefully read the [documentation of GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

You'll better write your script in some other language (e.g. [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html), [Python](https://python.org/), [Lua](https://lua.org/)). See the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) handling of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

You might also use [stat(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) and/or [gawk(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) and/or [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). See [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

You could be interested by [logrotate(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html) and [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) and [inotify(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).